# #define a global preprocessor directive in a separate file in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, c-preprocessor

I want to define a global preprocessor directive in my app. For example:

In **MyProgram.h**, I define:

```
#define USE_LOCALHOST
```

I import this file from beginning in **appDelegate.m**.

For the later use, in another file, I refer to this global preprocessor directive.

In **MyWebService.h**, I define:

```
#ifdef USE_LOCALHOST
static NSString *MY_SERVER = @"http://192.168.1.130:8888";
#else
static NSString *MY_SERVER = @"http://myserver.com";
#endif
```

However, the value of `MY_SERVER` is always @"http://myserver.com". How to make it work properly? Thanks.

Comment: USE_LOCALHOST, USE_LOCAL_HOST?

Comment: sorry, I just edited my post. Still the same question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define it in `.pch`. And you will never forget to include `.h`-file where you have defined `USE_LOCALHOST`.

Or you can define it in  build settings in `Preprocessor Macros`.
For example only for Debug.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be a good way to share the preprocessor directive among files.

Answer (score 2):

`#define` works only in the file where it's defined in. But you can `#import "MyProgram.h"` in `MyWebService.h` and problem solved. Every time you need to access `USE_LOCALHOST`, just import the header file.

Comment: I already imported the "MyProgram.h" right from the beginning in AppDelegate.m.

Comment: Not AppDelegate.m, but try to import it in MyWebService.h

Comment: Of course in that case, it will work. However, I don't want to do that. Each time, I need I have to give it a call to MyProgram.h. It's not the purpose of creating a global directive. Thanks to your response. Probably, my approach is wrong.